# How to use a variable as key in json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have following json formate

```
"[{"tempId":[{"cityName":"London"},{"weather":"overcast clouds"}]}]"
```

In above format **tempId is not a String-value it is a variable**.It's value is something like `"25Dec2013"`.But it is inserted as it is mean a name of variable and not a value.

So it should look like

```
"[{"tempId":[{"25Dec2013":"London"},{"weather":"overcast clouds"}]}]"
```

I have done following code.**I have written one comment in code where the actual problem is**.

```
var arrCityrecordForADay = [];
```

function getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, callback) {

```
var toDaysTimestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - (24 * 60 * 60);
for (var i in cityArray) {

    for (var j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=" + cityArray[i] + "&dt=" + toDaysTimestamp;

        $.ajax({
            url: jsonurl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            mimeType: "textPlain",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var arrCityRecordForDay = [];
                arrCityRecordForDay.push({
                    "cityName": data.list[0].city.name
                }, {
                    "weather": data.list[0].weather[0].description
                });

                var tempId = data.list[0].city.name+""+timeConverter(data.list[0].dt);
                arrCityrecordForADay.push({
                    tempId: arrCityRecordForDay // Here tempId is inserted as "tempId" not its value
                });

                if (((arrCityrecordForADay.length)) === cityArray.length) {
                    callback(arrCityrecordForADay);
                }

            }
        });
        toDaysTimestamp = toDaysTimestamp - (24 * 60 * 60);
    }
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  var cityArray = new Array();
  cityArray[0] = "pune";
  cityArray[1] = "london";
  var result = document.getElementById("msg");
  getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, function (jsonData) {
  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      console.log(myJsonString);
  });
});

function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){

 var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp*1000);

 var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

 var year = a.getFullYear();

 var month = months[a.getMonth()];
 var date = a.getDate();
 var hour = a.getHours();
 var min = a.getMinutes();
 var sec = a.getSeconds();
 //var time = date+','+month+' '+year+' '+hour+':'+min+':'+sec ;
 var time = date+''+month+''+year;
 return time;
}
```

**How to insert a variable as a key in above example?**

**EDIT:**

And Why output is not stable.Some time wrong and sometime correct.
Here is correct output:

```
"[{"Pune25Dec2013":[{"cityName":"Pune"},{"weather":"Sky is Clear"}]},{"London22Dec2013":[{"cityName":"London"},{"weather":"overcast clouds"}]}]"
```

Some times it shows following output after some refresh.

```
"[{"Pune24Dec2013":[{"cityName":"Pune"},{"weather":"Sky is Clear"}]},{"Pune25Dec2013":[{"cityName":"Pune"},{"weather":"Sky is Clear"}]}]"
```

How to overcome this?

*Your response will be appriciated !!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a temp variable to achieve this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[tempId] = arrCityRecordForDay;
arrCityrecordForADay.push(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you.It is working.There is some thing going wrong in working of code.I am unable to understand how javascript workflow is going.I have Edited question for this doubt.Will you please suggest something?